# Collisions for this?

Tags: collision-detection

If you watch this link of my game:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMWl8D_OwyM

If you watch this you will see the character can walk anywhere.. I want to add some collisions so he can only for example walk on the roads.. Is there some possible way to make this without makining a collision .txt that loads it up to an array??

Or how would i solve this the best way?? (The level is loaded from a picture)

Comment: Hi.  Please don't use language-specific tags (i.e. C++) unless your question is specifically related to that particular language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the level is a texture, you either sample the texture allowing the character to only walk on certain surfaces; or you can create a collision mask that is loaded separately and used purely for the collision detection.

How you implement this is up to you; and it may be simplest (and most productive) to just define an alternate data structure to contain the bounding boxes for all your collision objects.

**EDIT:**

The inverse may be the easier approach; instead of defining your objects, define the paths available to the character. This will severely limit free roam ability, but may be ideal for your example.

**EDIT2:**

**These aren't easy solutions**: it may be better for you to re factor your level data; don't just use a BITMAP, perhaps look at a simple tile based solution instead.

This would allow for easier distinction of surfaces, textures, and objects; and therefore, collision detection.

Comment: How would i make the only walking on certain surfaces ?? Could you maybe explain how this would work?